# surveyjs radiobutton load saved values does not highlight radiobutton

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

I have a survey which has radio group for user to select value. However, when I load the saved the json. The radio group does highlight the radio button. For example, I have choose 4 as the answer. When the save documents is loaded, it only show the 4th button with darker color but not
with the selected button highlighted. What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe conflict of css styles of different packages. Please, share live sample with the issue for more information

Comment: Thanks @potato. May I know what to share for live sample with the issue?

Comment: You can share issue to us via plunker example. Just open any of [examples on our site](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library?id=questiontype-radiogroup&platform=jQuery&theme=modern) in plunker and modify to reproduce you issue
[image tip](https://i.postimg.cc/7qDtXCHg/image.png)